# Comparar el value previo de un select y el nuevo para hacer una validacion React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

Estoy capturando el value del select y lo guardo en la variable number.

Lo que quiero hacer es que si esta en value 1 y cambie al value 2 muestre un modal, si esta en el value 2 y cambia al 3 muestre otro modal, y que no pueda hacer upgrate (osea que solo se pueda ir avanzando, no se pueda devolver a un numero menor) en caso tal tirar otro modal y quedarse en el numero actual.

```javascript
const [number, setNumber] = useState<string>("");

const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: string }>) => {
     setNumber(event.target.value);  
};

useEffect(() => {
     if(number === "1") {
       showWarning(true);
     } else if (number === "2") {
       showWarning(true);
     } else if (number === "3") {
       showWarning(true);
     }
}, [number]);
      
<select onChange={handleChange}>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hola, con respecto a los modales, qué has intentado hasta el momento? En dónde te trabaste o qué problema estás teniendo?. PD: Por favor agrega el código completo de tu componente, no solo el cuerpo (Ademas no estás devolviendo bien la vista)

Comment: Los modales los estoy manejando con material-ui, y el problema que tengo es como comparar esos values del select para porder hacer la validación. Estoy intentando con useRef

Comment: Por favor agrega todo el código pertinente